# jf rt glc fails to find objects in Artifactory to clean up

Tags: artifactory, git-lfs, jfrog-cli

I have a Git LFS repository which save image object files in Artifactory.
It had two branches: main and branch2. The main has only one README text file. The branch2 had 9 commits. The early commit added 8 image files. Then each of the following commits removed the 8 images and added new 8 images (Each image has different file name). After the 9th commit, the latest of branch2 still has 8 images. In Artifactory, it has created 32 objects.

The following command returns 32 objects:

```
curl -uUserName:userKey -X POST -H "Content-Type: text/plain" -d  'items.find({"repo":{"$eq":"ArtLFSRepoName"}})'  My_Artifactory_LFS_url/api/search/aql
```

I am trying to remove all the objects in Artifactory except the last 8 images by the command:

```
jf rt glc --repo="My_Artifactory_LFS_url"
```

The output of the command gave:
Found 8 files to keep, and 0 to clean

I created the third branch and cherry picked the last commit from branch2. Then I removed the branch2 in Git. I ran same `jf rt glc` command on the branch3. It still `Found 8 files to keep, and 0 to clean`. How can I remove the Artifactory object files which were added on an old already deleted Git branch?

I've also tried to run git garbage clean `git gc --aggressive` before running `jf rt glc`. It doesn't help. My jfrog version is `jf version 2.40.0`

Thanks for your help.